# Using wildcards with cat append target

Tags: linux, cat

I need to append the contents of two files to a third, where I don't know the exact file name of the target. Let's say it's named `targetXXXXX` where `XXXXX` is a random string. I am basically trying to do this:

```
cat file2 file3 >> target*
```

But of course that results in a file named `target*` rather than appending to the existing `targetXXXXX` file. Is there any way to do what I'm after?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Debian 5 (old) and Ubuntu 14.04.3 (recent)...works as expected...what is your Linux flavour ?

Comment: RHEL version 6.5. Added to original question to clarify what's happening vs desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, I think. This seems to do the trick:

```
cat file2 file3 >> `find -name 'target*'`
```